# How to run/open a c file in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a C program file in a folder. When I right-click on it and choose to open with other programs it doesn't show eclipse in the list of other programs.

Although I can start eclipse and it asks me to choose a workspace. By default, the workspace is in the C drive. But my C program file is in D drive. How do I open the C file in eclipse?

Comment: eclipse is an IDE. In a nutshell, you'll need to create project, import C source file into it, and then compile it.

Comment: Is workspace = project. So If I want to create a project in D drive then I would have to select that particular folder in D drive as workspace?

Comment: Is eclipse not showing in my program list normal ? Or is it something I have done wrong with the installation of it ?

Comment: This is more a question of your operating system. This beast has to assign C files to your favorite application, like Eclipse. You could add such an assignment yourself, please consult the documentation of your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is an IDE that requires a 'workspace'. This workspace is nothing but a directory residing in any of your drives where it can keep project-related files along with some meta information. Usually, you can create multiple projects within a single workspace. So, project *is not* a workspace, rather eclipse project(s) *resides* in a workspace.

To achieve what you are trying to do is very simple with these steps:

1. Launch eclipse
2. When it asks for a workspace location, note down the default it has proposed. It is typically a eclipse directory at C:/users//
3. Create a C/C++ project (Most likely console application or something similar verbatim)
4. Right click on project on your left, click add sources and select the C file you require
5. Build and observe the Console tab to check the build output

Note: The names for the options/steps I am suggesting may differ from what IDE you are using. I typically use eclipse-based IDEs for cross-compilers so the options may differ, but the concept is just the same.